# How do I run a PHP script from Wordpress environment, like `wp shell`?

Tags: wp-cli

[`wp shell`](https://developer.wordpress.org/cli/commands/shell/) is a very useful tool that lets you run PHP statements and expressions interactively, from within a Wordpress environment. It lets you use all the functions, classes and globals that you can use within Wordpress.

Is there a similar tool that will let me run a PHP file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is! I didn't find it at first, but wp cli offers a command called `eval-file` which does what you want:

```
$ echo '<?php echo is_wp_error("foo") ? 1 : 0;' > example.php
$ wp eval-file example.php
0
```

Comment: `eval()` function is the most dangerous thing to play with in the world of PHP programming.

Comment: @JackJohansson `eval-file`, when used on a file name, actually does not use eval, it includes the file: https://github.com/wp-cli/eval-command/blob/master/src/EvalFile_Command.php